# error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '[' token ....... for UIButton in XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am getting the following error while building the code for creating the buttons in XCode:

> error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before '[' token   ....... for UIButton in XCode

Following is the code :

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


    @interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

UIButton *signInButton;
[signInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

    -(IBAction)buttonClicked : (id)sender;

    @end
```

Any suggestions to solve the error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Give some time to read the basics of objective c would be very beneficial for you.

Answer (score 2):

You're putting implementation code into the interface declaration. That's not where it should be.

The button should be declared in the interface and then implemented in the implementation block in your .m file.

I suggest you pick up a book on iOS development, perhaps the Big Nerd Ranch guide to iPhone Development?

Comment: how (and where) to write the following code in the implementation file [signInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; int he interface file. Also do we need to import any file related to UIButton

Comment: This is why you need to buy a book.

Answer (score 0):

> [signInButton addTarget:self
>   action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
>   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

is actual code, and shouldn't go in your interface (.h file). The interface is for prototyping and defining locals and props. Im guessing your doing this programatically, if you are, you don't need the IBOutlet, and IBAction. For beginners, its probably better to do this in interface builder..

Your interface (.h file) should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {

UIButton *_signInButton;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIButton * signInButton;

-(IBAction)buttonClicked :(id)sender;

@end
```

Your implementation (.m file) should look like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize signInButton=_signInButton;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.signInButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_POS, Y_POS, 30, 30)];

[self.signInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.signInButton setTitle:@"PRESS ME" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.view addSubview:self.signInButton];

}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked :(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"CLICKED!");
//THE BUTTON WAS CLICKED, DO STUFF
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
[_signInButton release];_signInButton=nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hey Luke  thanks for your quick reply ... Sorry for stupid question but I am still a newbie in iPhone programming... Just wondering can you give an sample code of how to write [signInButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; int he interface file

Comment: Everyone has to start somewhere. Usually beginners do this using the interface builder. However, once you get on your feet, many provide functionality like this programatically like how you have done. See my edited answer..

Answer (score 0):

Just clean and build again. It works for me